# How can i avoid or minimise TimeoutException's from Instagram using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, timeout, instagram

I have developed a successful Instagram (IG) bot, using Python and Selenium, that allows me to post, like, and follow.

I have noticed that every few days, my bot runs into a problem, whereby it is getting a TimeoutException. I think this is because IG update their website/change the source code.

I wanted to share (1) the method/functions I have developed for finding the web elements and (2) some of the elements, to see if there is a better way for me to do this, to avoid future issues with my bot. Or, do I need to accept that I need to update the list of XPATHS etc on a regular basis when IG updates/change their site.

The code below shows one of the main functions I use. This takes a list of possible paths and a time delay as inputs. It then tries to find each element, typically by XPATH and then return this, if there is a TimeoutException, it will try the next possible path in my list.

```
def try_selenium_timeout_clickable(input_possible_paths_list, input_time_delay):
for loop_possible_path in input_possible_paths_list:
    very_short_sleep()
    try:
        print('Trying a path')
        element_we_want = WebDriverWait(driver, input_time_delay ,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,loop_possible_path)))
        return(element_we_want)
    except TimeoutException:
        print('TimeoutException - trying different path')
```

Two examples of elements that have changed and caused me some issues in the past are, (1) the little cross at the top right of a post that closes the post and (2) the little heart icon on a post for liking the post. Examples of the lists that i pass into the 'try_selenium_timeout_clickable' function are below.

```
close_post_possible_paths_list = ["/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/svg/path", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]"]    

like_button_possible_paths_list = ["/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div[1]/svg", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button"]
```

**My questions**

1. Does anyone know why i regularly get TimeoutException's - is this because IG changes/updates their source code?
2. Is there a better way for me to reference the elements in the lists above or indeed a better way for me to do this overall, so as to avoid or minimise any TimeoutException's and changes to the XPATH's in the future?

Answer (score 1):

In general I try to avoid leveraged xpaths as much as possible, unless I'm trying to target a WebElement using only its inner text (and it doesn't have a title property), and when I do so I try to ensure that they're relatively flexible, e.g. div[@class='whatever']//div[contains(@class, 'another-class')]

I would hazard a guess that you're running into difficulties as the xpaths you're using are too brittle, 'this div must have a X div children which must have Y div children which much have Z children".

I had a little look at the IG dom and it seems like you could just use a CssSelector to target the close button relatively easily
close_button_path = "div[role='button'] [aria-label='Close']"

The like button is a little trickier as the CssSelector that I would use (button[type='button'] [aria-label='Like']) returns two WebElements, so we can use an Xpath to find these two elements and then get the ancestor button element (of which there is only one).
like_button_xpath = "//button[@type='button']//*[@aria-label="Like"]//ancestor::button"

tl;dr
Your xpaths are very brittle, try to avoid targeting one element after another if you can just jump straight down to the element in question:

close_button_css = "div[role='button'] [aria-label='Close']"

like_button_xpath = "//button[@type='button']//*[@aria-label="Like"]//ancestor::button"

Comment: Hi @RJB. Thank you for the very useful and comprehensive response. Is there any resources you can recommend to me, for learning more about CssSelectors and how to use less brittle paths? Or is this a case of learning by doing?